# Make sleep or get someone sleep

Tags: syntactic-analysis

How can I rephrase "I made the child sleep" without the word ' make' ?

Comment: There isn’t really a word for causing someone to sleep since it’s not possible to directly cause someone to sleep (with the possible exception of hypnotism). You can _lull_ or _sing_ them to sleep, you can _bore_ them to sleep, or you can even knock them unconscious and make them ‘sleep’, but you’re not actually **making** them sleep in any of those cases: you’re just providing better circumstances for their natural need/desire for sleep to overtake them, in the same way the rocking of a boat or train often does.

Answer (score 1):

It's common to say "**I *put* the child *to bed***". "[**Put to bed**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_to_bed)" means to help or prepare someone to go to sleep, and would be commonly said of a child being directed to go to their bed, tucked in, etc.

There is a similar phrase "[**put to sleep**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_to_sleep)" which can also mean to directly *cause* someone to sleep or render them unconscious; but it has a secondary euphemistic meaning "to kill", so it may not be appropriate in all circumstances.

Comment: also: tuck sb in?

Comment: As someone who always had trouble sleeping as a child (even back then I was a night owl), I have to disagree that _put to bed_ is appropriate here. My parents may have put me to bed at 8 PM, but it would usually be another hour or so until I actually slept. For infants, the two are closer to being synonymous, since putting a baby to bed usually entails sitting by the bed until the baby actually sleeps; but for older children, they can be quite far apart.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Oh, I agree that the attempt may not be successful! But it's admittedly hard to know exactly which usages OP is looking for with "I made the child slee[."

Comment: @MarkBeadles I agree – that’s why I voted to put the question on hold as unclear. It should really be clarified before being answered.

Comment: You could say "I got the child off to sleep".

Answer (score 0):

**lull to sleep** [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lull+to+sleep)

> to quiet and comfort someone to sleep.

As in:

> "I lulled the child sleep"

to **lull**:  To cause to sleep or rest; soothe or calm.